# I Don't Like My Neighbors (Riddle)

Tags: riddle

I don't like my neighbors.
One of them wishes I would move
so that he can visit the others on our street.
The other is stuck up
and only associates with one color.
I can't stand to be in either of their homes.
...at least, not while they're in them.

Who am I?

**This riddle has been solved.

These are the hints I would have provided, had they been necessary:**
1.

> I met someone **just like me** who lives at the other end of my street!

2.

> I met someone across the street who appears to be royalty. Next time I see him, **I'll have to check.**

3.

> I met a short individual *(in passing)* who said she was **looking to get a promotion.**

*This is my first question ever on Stack Exchange! Hope this riddle is neither too easy nor too hard.

Good luck!*

Comment: I like the clues!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> [image: chess pieces]

You are

> The knight chess piece

I don't like my neighbors.

> When you move, you won't be next to either.

One of them wishes I would move
so that he can visit the others on our street.

> The rook needs you out of the way to move along the back row.

The other is stuck up
and only associates with one color.

> The bishop moves diagonally so always stays on the same colour.

I can't stand to be in either of their homes.
...at least, not while they're in them.

> You can't take your own pieces or have two pieces in one square.

---

### Alternatively,

You are

> The queen chess piece

Most of the answers are the same:

I don't like my neighbors.

> They get in the way of you moving.

One of them wishes I would move
so that he can visit the others on our street.

> The king needs you out of the way to castle safely.

The other is stuck up
and only associates with one color.

> The bishop moves diagonally so always stays on the same colour.

I can't stand to be in either of their homes.
...at least, not while they're in them.

> You can't take your own pieces or have two pieces in one square.

Comment: Excellent! The Knight was the answer I was looking for. The Queen and King are also reasonable answers, and I didn't have anything in the riddle to *clearly* eliminate them as possibilities, though the line about "visiting others" was intended to mean that this neighbor was by himself, isolated from the other pieces because of the Knight.

Comment: Nice username, I must say!

Answer (score 7):

> [image]

Precise Answer

> Edge Cells of a Rubix Cube precisely.

One of them wishes I would move

> This is the center cell of each of the sides. In a Rubix Cube, this is the static cells and the others which are not of the same colour should move out of that side.

The other is stuck up
and only associates with one color.

> Every cell of the cube is of a single colour

I can't stand to be in either of their homes.

> And each coloured cell has their own home or side

Comment: A good guess, but not correct. =) Your interpretation of the wording is accurate in some places, though!

Comment: @Bulldogg6404: Unless you want us to be psychic, I would really love to know, why this answer is wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, you were the only one to give an answer so far.  It would be inappropriate to give away the actual answer so soon. I'm not discouraging you from thinking up other possible answers! I do have some hints ready to provide, if they are needed.

Comment: @Abhijit First, riddles are always a little bit on the "too broad" side and often the answer with the most number of UV and the accepted answer differ. If you answer is good, people will acknowledge it. Second, I cannot see how your answer explains the final part.

Comment: @dmg Riddles aren't _always_ on the "too broad" side. If they're designed well enough, there's a single unique answer and nothing else fits. Sadly the quality here on SE has gone downhill since our best riddlers left, and there aren't many good riddles left.

Comment: That does it. I'll see if I can conjure a nasty one.