# My Wacky Neighbors (What am I?)

Tags: riddle

(This riddle was inspired by [bulldogg6404](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9319/bulldogg6404)'s ["I Don't Like My Neighbors"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/9234/i-dont-like-my-neighbors-riddle)!)

My neighbors are wacky!
One of them's a single-minded psycho who just likes cutting things up!
The other one's two-faced and doesn’t like children.
They both have neighbors like them, but neither of them are like me.
I guess I’ll just continue being I...

Who am I?

Comment: I feel like an inspiration! :D

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Close to Narmer's answer, I think you are a:

> Human Adult Canine Tooth

One of them's a single-minded psycho who just likes cutting things up!

> As mentioned in Narmer's answer, the incisors are used to cut and tear meat and these also have a single edge to do so.

The other one's two-faced and doesn’t like children.

> The premolars.  They are two edges (faces) and they are in permanent teeth but not primary (baby) teeth.

They both have neighbors like them, but neither of them are like me.

> Both the incisors and premolars have another incisor or premolar next to them but there are no adjacent canines.

I guess I’ll just continue being I...

> In the dental formula, the top/bottom sections are written as 2.1.2.3 with the 1 being the canines (and I is the roman numeral for 1).

Comment: Bravo, that's it! (I was trying to reference "eyetooth" for the last, but your reasoning works as well).

Answer (score 7):

I think that you are a:

> **spoon** at a table setting with knives and forks

One of them's a single-minded psycho who just likes cutting things up!

> This describes the knife.

The other one's two-faced and doesn’t like children.

> This describes the fork.  Two-faced and FORKed tongue are both expressions for lying and deceit.  Also, children do not usually use forks.

They both have neighbors like them, but neither of them are like me.

> This suggests different types of knifes (dinner, butter, steak) and different types of forks (salad, dinner, lobster). But none are like a spoon.

Comment: Clever, and at first I thought the same answer as you. However, it was unclear to me how the two-faced/doesn't-like-children clue matched up. You say there aren't any other kinds of spoons, but this isn't true - off the top of my head, I can think of the normal spoon, the soup spoon, and the serving spoon, all of which may be found at a table setting. **spoiler** I also considered it being the plate, having silverware as its neighbors, but again, I'm not confident in the same clue mentioned.

Comment: Darn! I was hoping my riddle narrowed the field down enough, but this answer, even though it fits the wording pretty well, was not the intended answer. There is a clue hidden in the fifth line as well, by the way. I may post some hints/edit the riddle for less ambiguity if no one gets what I was going for.

Comment: Don't worry Sumelic. Give it some more time, I am sure we can figure something out.

Comment: Very true, I misinterpreted.

Answer (score 3):

You are:

> The **rock** of rock, paper, scissors.

My neighbors are wacky!
One of them's a single-minded psycho who just likes cutting things up!

> The scissors. No explanation needed.

The other one's two-faced and doesn't like children.

> The paper. Two faced and children usually don't are very kind with it :(

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too confident, but @Abhijit gave me an idea with his deck of cards thought:

> **The Joker in a deck of cards.**

My neighbors are wacky!
One of them's a single-minded psycho who just likes cutting things up!

> The ace in most cases is valued at one point, and as mentioned in his answer, performs cuts in the game of Bridge.

The other one's two-faced and doesn't like children.

> Any face card in a standard deck (King, Queen, Jack) has two faces, and I guess they don't like kids because there aren't any represented in the deck.

They both have neighbors like them, but neither of them are like me.

> There are multiple of each card in a standard deck, which is how it is referenced here as having neighbors like them. Admittedly, despite most games that use the Joker only need one in the deck, there are commonly two Jokers provided, so this doesn't quite work either. *However*, the thing each Joker has all to itself is a lack of suit. The face cards and aces both have many neighbors of the same suit, but the Joker - either one - has no suit.

I guess I'll just continue being I...

> The joker, being a bit of a clown, is considered in royal stories to be having a mindset all his own, and would think of the rest of the world as being strange for not sharing in his quirky nature. This might also explain why he thinks his neighbors are wacky.

*If this is correct, I'd like it to be appended to @Abhijit's post and give him best-answer.*

> Edit: Some ideas for myself when I wake up or anyone else who happens upon this: imaginary number i, arithmetic operators, or Iodine on the periodic table.

Comment: As I commented at Abhijit's post, the answer I was thinking of isn't related to cards...

Comment: Darn! Oh well. I'm going to bed, so if it isn't solved by tomorrow morning, I'll take another stab at it.

Answer (score 2):

You are:

> The tongue.

My neighbors are wacky!
One of them's a single-minded psycho who just likes cutting things up!

> The incisor teeth, used to cut meat.

The other one's two-faced and doesn't like children.

> Wisdom tooth. Two faced because it's called wisdom tooth but comes only with pain (ah! I trusted you, wisdom tooth!). Or because it should help the already existing molars but in fact is useless. Also children doesn't have it.

They both have neighbors like them, but neither of them are like me.

> There are 32 teeth with various functions, but no one is like the tongue.

Comment: This is actually really close! On the right track!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are one among

> [image]
>  A non value card of a particular suit and value ex. 2 of spades.

One of them's a single-minded psycho who just likes cutting things up!

> [image]
>  In a game of bridge (particularly NT), an Ace of a colour rules  over the rest. For non-NT game, an ACE of the trump rules can **CUT** any hand. And **single-minded** because Ace is often counted as 1 before the number cards 2,3 ..... as in A, 2, 3, ....... 10, J, Q, K

The other one's two-faced and doesn’t like children.

> [image]
>  Ohh never heard them conjugating and having children.

They both have neighbors like them, but neither of them are like me.

> Any card is unique and no two are the same.

Comment: I like this line of thought! However, are you saying that the "I" in the riddle refers to the deck? Or a specific card?

Comment: @Bulldogg6014: Any non-valued card 2 through 10. Pick one with a value and suit to make it unique.

Comment: I don't know. It seems rather ambiguous for the answer to be one of a large range of cards. I'm posting a similar answer, and crediting you with the line of thought. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, my answer doesn't have anything to do with playing cards (although I can see how you got there from my use of "two-faced"!)